# Input: Sequential right-most digits of format string

Tags: angularjs, input, material-design

I'm trying to design an input form where users can scan a barcode or enter the trailing significant digits. When the users scan the barcode, the format is `AAA111000000000000000000012345`. The USB scanner acts just like a keyboard. When entering by hand, it's easier to just enter the trailing significant digits (`12345`) and autofill the rest.

I'm using angular/material design, and am trying to design an input that gracefully handles both. I'd like to preload the input field with `AAA111000000000000000000000000`, and as the user enters each number, they replace the right-most 0's. This would work with the scanner.

I've tried to search for this, but I don't know how to describe exactly what I'm trying to do succinctly enough.

What UI/UX would work best here?